# module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Вот мой код :

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.Telebot('ТОКЕН')
bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
bot.polling()
```

понимаю тут толком нет ничего , но уже выдает ошибку :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/projects/bot/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = telebot.Telebot('ТОКЕН')
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'
```

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема

Answer (score 2):

`B` должна быть прописная: `telebot.TeleBot`.